# Real-time star map

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, gui

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and I was wondering if there is any sort of graphical application which shows you all the planets and stars etc that are above you (based on your location which you should be able to customize or it should be able to automatically detect), and gives you information about how they are moving and what they are etc? It should also be able to give you star mappings.

Comment: Have you tried `stellarium`?

Comment: @Terrance: You know it was funny, as soon as I posted the question I found it! :D

Comment: Glad you found it!  :D

Comment: `kstars` is also nice, although it will load a lot of kde libs. Which I have for k3b anyways... ;-)

Comment: @Rmano: Sounds nice, though Stellarium sounds more advanced and has less dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a great application called `Stellarium` which can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install stellarium
```

[image]

Here is a list of some of its features:

- default star catalogue with over 600 thousand stars
- information about the brightest stars (spectral type, distance, etc.)
- downloadable star catalogue extensions, for up to 210 million stars
- all New General Catalogue (NGC) objects
- images of almost all Messier objects and the Milky Way
- real time positions of the planets and their satellites
- 13 different cultures with their constellations
- artistic illustrations of the 88 Western constellations
- very realistic atmosphere, sunrise and sunset
- 7 panoramic landscapes (more can be made or downloaded from the website)
- scripting with ECMAScript
- plug-in support: Stellarium comes with 8 plug-ins by default, including:
- artificial satellites plug-in (updated from an on-line TLE database)
- ocular simulation plug-in (shows how objects look like in a given ocular)
- Solar System editor plug-in (imports comet and asteroid data from the MPC)
- telescope control plug-in (Meade LX200 and Celestron NexStar compatible)