# Real-time planetarium

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, 15.10

After finding [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/690284/364819), I started wondering if there was some more real-time software out there which would cover a wider range to the software that I found there, or at least so that I could observe those more closely with more detail. So is there any software out there that has at least the following features?:

- Is in real-time
- Can show you information and models of planets and other known objects in the solar system (or beyond)
- Can show you information about specific things on planets (e.g.: locations on Earth and craters on other planets)
- Has the ability to show star maps
- Allows you to view the orbits of objects
- Has a level high of detail (good quality images and models)
- Allows you to freely move around

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Celestia` is just the app you were looking for!

You can install it with this if you use **GNOME**:

```
sudo apt-get install celestia-gnome
```

And with this if you use something else:

```
sudo apt-get install celestia
```

**Description:**

> Real-time visual space simulation Celestia is a free
>   3D astronomy program. Based on the Hipparcos Catalogue, it allows
>   users to display objects ranging in scale from artificial satellites
>   to entire galaxies in three dimensions using OpenGL. Unlike most
>   planetarium software, the user is free to travel about the Universe.

The `celestia-gnome` package contains the GTK+ frontend for Celestia, and integrates with GNOME.

**Screenshots:**

[image: Earth]

[image: Sun]

[image: Orbits]

[image: Saturn]

[image: Star Maps]

[image: Craters]

[image: Milky Way]

[image: International Space Station]